# retrevial of Item Name from GUID in a Multilist Sitecore

Tags: xslt, sitecore

```
<xsl:template match="*"> 
<xsl:variable name="ids" select="concat(sc:fld('MyMultilist',.)'|')"/> 
<xsl:call-template name="PrintTitles">   
<xsl:with-param name="ids" select="$ids"/> 
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="PrintTitles">  
<xsl:param name="ids"/>  
<xsl:if test="$ids">    
<xsl:variable name="itm_id" select="substring-before($ids, '|')"/>    
<xsl:if test="$itm_id">      
<xsl:variable name="itm" select="sc:item($itm_id,.)"/>      
value : <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title', $itm)" br/>
</xsl:if>    
<xsl:call-template name="PrintTitles">      
<xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-after($ids, '|')"/>    
</xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We are able to retieve the GUIDs of the items from the above code but unable to print the title( Item Name ) of the particular selected item in the Multilist . In the  following line of code trying to retrieve name of selected Item by GUID .

```
value : <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title', $itm)" br/>
```

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

You get an item using `sc:item` XSL extension. Just get the item name from it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sc:item($itm_id, .)/@name" />
```